# Unable to close FragmentActivity correctly

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm facing a strange problem inside my app. From a fragment, if i push a button, i start new FragmentActivity that contains a fragment and some other elements, but if i would go back to previous Activity (that contain fragment that start the current activity), i need to push back button twice.
First time fragmentActivity seem close itself, but it reopens again. I close FragmentActivity as always:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
}
```

so what's wrong?

Comment: I used for finish FragmentActivity with Button in Fragment interface implementing. When do you want code example write to comment.

Answer (score 0):

> i start new FragmentActivity that contains a fragment and some other elements

You're most likely adding that `FragmentTransaction` to the backstack, which is why it's consuming the back button press. You shouldn't need to override `onBackPressed()` at all. Instead, look at the code where you add the `Fragment` to the new `FragmentActivity` and ensure you're not calling `.addToBackStack()` on the initial transaction. For example, typically in `onCreate()` you would do something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.your_container_id, new YourInitialFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't call addToBackStack